# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am simply trying to test my connection with SQL Server 2008 as follows:

```
public class ForJDBC {


    public static void main(String[] args) {




        try{

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://XX.XX.X.XXX:1433;databaseName=MyDB;user=sa;password=mypassword");

        if(conn != null){

            System.out.println("Connection is Successfull");
        }

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){

           ex.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
}
```

But I keep on getting the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:96f7d048-9734-4fd8-8216-21231d89b2e6
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at forjdbc.ForJDBC.main(ForJDBC.java:35)
```

When I connect to MySQL 5.5, it works fine.

***Troubleshooting Steps I have followed:***

1) Tried Logging with the "sa" user name and password within the SQL Server Management Console
using SQL Server Management studio

2) I have sqljdbc4.jar in my Source Package folder of Netbeans 7.4

3) Updated to Java 8

Please let me know what am I doing wrong and let me know if I can answer any questions.

Comment: have you checked the below link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458841/sqlserverexception-login-failed-for-user-sa

Comment: Yes, I have checked many posts on the SO. Based on the above link, I do have a user on my name and permission granted to connect to SQL in SSMS.

Comment: Could this be a problem http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2653857 considering that I am not allowed to make any changes to SQL Server 2008 ?

Answer (score -1):

Connection String Problem...

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

Connection connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Tema6","sa","123456")

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed loading the Driver class and registering it.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

If still it is not working then please ensure your SQLServer services is running

Answer (score -3):

Click SQL --> click right mouse --> propretise --> Securiti -->tick SQL server and windows Authentication mode

90% success!